# How do I minimize Dragonvale load time?

Tags: technical-issues, ios, dragonvale

I have an iPhone 4s, and most games load pretty quick. In addition, most games load instantly once they are in memory (ie one of my last 4 or so apps loaded). In contrast, with Dragonvale I get a load screen almost every time I lock my phone, or switch apps. Does anyone else have this problem?  Is it just expected, or is there a way to reduce/eliminate it?  If relevant, I am still running iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: do you get double load screens? It used to log out/back in and reload every time game center logged back but an update fixed it. I haven't had the problem since.

Comment: Also note this is an online-only game, so load times are a function of your internet speed. Is it slow even on quick wi fi?

Comment: I didn't realize that it was online only.  I bet that is it.  My 3G performance has been not super awesome recently, so I I expect that is why it seems to load so fast when at home, but not when I'm out.  I would accept that as the answer, if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dragonvale used to have major load-time issues, so make sure you're on the latest version. It used to load the game twice, and it reloaded every time another app opened. I don't *think* iOS 5.1 is required for the latest updates, but I'd still recommend it.

However, it sounds like your specific problem is because "loading" Dragonvale actually happens from their servers; it's thus dependent on your internet connection speed. Slow internet will cause slow Dragonvale loading.

Playing it at home on WiFi is probably the best way to make sure the game loads quickly, but it still depends on your internet speed.